# Add submitHandler to jQuery validate() at run time

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I'm using [jQuery mt-select](https://github.com/easy-development/jquery-mt-select) to manage auto-completed selections from a list of thousands of possibilities.

The form initializes with a text input like

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="location[]" data-mt-filter-control="" autocomplete="on" style="width: auto;">
```

Then as selections are added hidden inputs are appended like

```
<input type="hidden" name="locationID[1]" value="1786" data-tag-id="1786">
```

I want for these forms to add a jQuery validate submitHandler after validate() has initialized in the main JavaScript file.  This would check to be sure at least one of the required selections has been made.

When selections exist (or not) I have verified `$("input[name^='locationID']").length` gives the expected values.  However the form returns valid whether or not they exist leading me to believe that the submitHandler is not being added.

There are no errors or warnings in console and validate() behaves otherwise as expected where class `required` is applied to non hidden fields.

So why is the submitHandler not firing?

On the page with this form I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $( "form" ).validate({
      submitHandler: function(form) {
            if($("input[name^='locationID']").length > 0) {
                 //Form is valid
                 alert('form data valid');
                 form.submit();
            }
            else {
                 //Form is invalid
                 alert('form data invalid');
            }
        },
      errorPlacement: function(error, element){
            if(element.attr("name") == "locationID[]"){
                error.appendTo($('#errorbox'));
                console.log('saw error');
            }else{
                error.appendTo( element.parent().next() );
                console.log('other errors');
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

And in the main JS file for all pages I initialize validate() like so:

```
$("form").validate({
        ignore: [], // include hidden fields
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) { 
            if ( element.is(":radio") ) {
                error.appendTo ( '#' + element.attr('name') + '_multiError' ); // eg rad_22_multiError
            } else if ( element.is(":checkbox") ) {
               error.appendTo ( '#' + element.attr('name').replace(/[\[\]]+/g,'') + '_multiError' );
            } else {
                error.appendTo( element.parent() );
            }
        },
        rules: {
            antispam: { equalToParam: "events" }
        }                      
    });
```

Comment: Two issues.  One described by @charlietfl below... you cannot initialize the plugin more than once.  The second is that you should not be doing any more validation inside of the `submitHandler`.  By definition, this handler only fires on button click _when the form is valid_; makes absolutely no sense to be sending a "invalid form" message from there... there are plenty of other opportunities to ensure the form is fully valid long _before_ the `submitHandler` is called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two initialization instances won't combine the options of each other, the second will overwrite the first.

What you could do is break out the options into a stored object variable and extend them based on form class if that class exists.

Something like:

```
var validateOpts = {
    ignore: [],
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {...},
    rules: {...}
}

var extraOpts ={
    submitHandler:function(){...} 
    errorPlacement: function(error, element){...}
}

var $form =$('form');
 /* see if we need to combine the options or not */
if($form.is('.specialFormClass') ){
   /* yup...needs extending */
   $.extend( validateOpts, extraOpts);
}
/* now init the validation */
$form.validate(validateOpts);
```

Comment: Actually, the _first_ instance will take precedence over any others.  With the `.validate()` method, all subsequent calls are ignored.

Comment: @sparky, didn't know that, I guess it checks for `data()`? Anyway hard to even tell which was first or last in OP ... extending and initializing only once is still most sensible I think

Comment: Never examined the core for the reason, but from experience, it's always only the first instance that matters.  Yes, your answer seems sound.

Comment: Although, the OP should not be doing more validation inside of the `submitHandler`. By definition, this handler only fires on button click *when the form is valid*; it makes absolutely no sense to be doing validation and sending a "invalid form" message from the `submitHandler` when there are plenty of other opportunities to ensure the form is fully valid long *before* the `submitHandler` is called.

Comment: @Sparky and charliefl - headed to bed will check this in AM.  Did not know onSubmit was contingent on valid() being true.  What I need to do is validate() that at least one hidden field exists in form.  Thank you for the $.extend example!  Any advice on using validate() to check that at least one hidden with name matching input[name^='locationID'] exists?

Comment: @jerrygarciuh, as long as `ignore` option is set to `[]`, you can validate any hidden field.  Just set the `required` rule on `locationID` no different than any other field.  If the field does not exist then the rule will simply be ignored.

Comment: @Sparky thank you for reply.  Issue is that what I want to validate is that at least one exists.  If none have been created by the mt-select process then I need to declare form invalid and prompt user to use mt-select element to make a selection.

Comment: @jerrygarciuh, then I would create another hidden field that always contains the result and create a custom validation method that's attached to that one.  See the `addMethod()` method for creating your own rule.

Comment: Appreciate the help from both of y'all.  Have this working and have improved understanding of this plugin now!  Thank you!